# How to write output of command to a text file but not execute them?

Tags: command-line

How can I redirect the output of any command to a text file without executing the command ? For example, I would like to confirm the files that would get zipped before running

`zip -r point_clouds.zip data/*/*/point_clouds`

by writing the output into a text file e.g.

`zip -r point_clouds.zip data/*/*/point_clouds | tee test.txt`

or a delete operation

`find . -name "*.tif" -type 'f' -size -160k | tee test.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve that for a command in general, you will need to check whether the command provides a flag that allows it to simulate an operation rather than carrying it out. For example, with `apt`, you have a `-s` or `--simulate` flag. With `rsync`, you have the `--dry-run` option. Such flags tell the program to "pretend" doing the job, but not actually do it, so just report.

Not sure whether `zip` has such an option. You will probably need to effectively create the .zip file, eventually in a temp folder if need be, to obtain the list of what will be (is being) zipped. On the other hand, just an `ls data/*/*/point_clouds` would already retrieve a list of files that will be zipped.

For your `find` example: you already provided the answer yourself. Currently, you are just writing out a list of files. If you want to effectively delete them, you can add the `--exec rm` option.